# Threading WebBrowser in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, com, browser

I have 2 methods in a class (`login()` and `change()`).

In that class I also have a property (`webBrownser wb`)

I call the `login()` by thread

```
Thread tLogin = new Thread(b.doLogin);
tLogin.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
tLogin.Start();
```

and the method `change()` by thread too

```
 Thread tLike = new Thread(b.autoLike);
 tLike.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
 tLike.Start();
```

But when the method `change()` try use property `wb` I receive this message:

> *COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be
>   used.*

What am I doing wrong?

The methods are synchronized with `lock()`...

Comment: You will have to create a new instance of the browser.  The old one is dead after the thread that owns it terminated.

Answer (score 0):

A WebBrowser is a COM (or ActiveX) component.  It can't be used on any other thread than the one that created with object.  And that thread needs to have a message pump (e.g. `Application.Run` in WinForms).

For more detail on how to do this, see [WebBrowser Control in a new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269800/webbrowser-control-in-a-new-thread)

Comment: Yes, anything you do to `WebBrowser` on a thread needs to be done on the same thread that created it and that thread needs to have a message pump.